# Kibana 4 time window in date histograms

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, kibana-4, nosql

I have a Date Histogram chart in Kibana 4 that is suppose to show how many new entries are inserted in elasticsearch. For that, every entry has a date field.

I've defined the chart to show new entries every minute, but I want to limit the time window (for example, show me only the last entries of the last 4 hours). I've tried to use the Time Filter provided in the dashboard, but it seems not to be working. So it is showing how many new entries were inserted since the first entry.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the time window being shown is between 11pm yesterday until 10am today. How can I limit the time window to 4 hours (so from 6am to 10 am) to be shown on the chart?

Here is the query Kibana is sending to Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "cr_date",
        "interval": "1m",
        "pre_zone": "+01:00",
        "pre_zone_adjust_large_interval": true,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "manufacturer",
            "size": 100,
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I solved the issue. The thing is the time based key needs to be selected when a index pattern is being configured in Kibana. More pricisely checking the Index contains time-based events and selecting the right field expected to be the timestamp. Apparently I didn't selected the key I was expecting to be the time-based key. It is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

The time window of a specific visualization isn't part of the data saved on that visualization. This is so anyone viewing your search/visualisation can decide the time-window they want to view it in.

To change this, you have a button in the top right corner of kibana, which adjusts the time window for the whole page you're currently viewing.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it but it didn't change the chart view. It still shows the time windows since the first insertion. The image on my original post this Time Filter is 30 minutes.